# Checkbox in TemplateField in Gridview loses checked on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, postback

I have a gridview with a template field.  In that template field is a checkbox.  I have a submit button outside of the gridview to assign the records that were checked.  On the postback no checkboxes register as being checked.  Here is my Code:

```
<Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cb" Checked="false" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCFID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataField="DOB" HeaderText="Date of Birth" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Gender" DataField="Gender"  />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status"  />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Plan Name" DataField="PlanName"  />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Type" DataField="ControlType"  />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Date of Service" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" htmlencode="false" DataField="DateofService"  />
            </Columns>

protected void AssignRecords(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Rows = gvASH.Rows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
    {
        //CheckBoxField cb = ((CheckBoxField)gvASH.Rows[i].Cells[1]).;
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gvASH.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("cb");
        Label lblID = (Label)gvASH.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("lblCFID");
        if (cb.Checked == true)
        {

            string ID = lblID.Text;
            //Assign Code
        }
    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint set on the string ID = lblID.Text; but it never finds any that are checked.

Comment: I'm using C#, but this example from the asp.net website in VB.Net is basically doing exactly what I'm doing:  http://www.asp.net/Learn/data-access/tutorial-52-vb.aspx

So I know it's possible, I just don't know why it's not working for me.

Comment: When is the page lifecycle is your method to assign being called?

Comment: Check out the Solution here, you need to persist selection checkbox http://highoncoding.com/Articles/697_Persisting_CheckBox_State_While_Paging_in_GridView_Control.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think what you are missing is, when you click on the button and your page is postback, you rebinding to gridview, you need to bind in this condition like

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSourceID = "yourDatasourceID";
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: You're right, I just put a break point on the search method, and it is being called again.  I'll have to track down where it's being called from.

Answer (score 1):

On a postback, the contents of the GridView are re-created from the postback Viewstate data between page_init and page_load.  Perhaps try examining your Gridview in page_load to see what's there.

Answer (score 0):

set the autopostback attribute of Checkbox

```
AutoPostBack="true"
```